# How to get RMA item attribute value in magento1?

Tags: magento-1.9, rma

I have created a custom RMA item attribute from magento admin and now i want to fetch its value for a particular RMA.

[image]

for example, as shown in image above **Item condition** is RMA item attribute. and i want to fetch its value i.e, Damaged.

So, how can i do this? Can anyone suggest me something..?

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your code from where its coming?

Comment: This is admin and it is already created.i have created a new attribute value. I want to know just from where we can get these RMA attribute values?

Comment: I know its created but I need to know where are you storing these data?

Comment: Actually my question is this where these value are stored?

Comment: Are you using any extension? Then you need to check the extension's tables.

Comment: Check your database. You will find table for that. If you are not able to fetch using model then you can write direct sql query for fetch value.

Comment: @user55548  can u pls give me that sql query or using model ?

Comment: Without your module it is not possible. You can do it by direct sql query also. Just find table and write sql query.